# WordCount in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I'm trying to count the amount of
occurences of every word in a text
to then represent it as a list of tuples.

I've tried by using an accumulator
and I've tried by using the concat
and filter. What occurs to be the
problem is that I'm not sure how to deal with lists inside a list.

I'm not sure how to continue from here, I tried to call the function wordCountt using filter (x /=) on the argument but that wouldn't run for some reason. Would really appreciate some guidance here.

Cheers

````
type Document = [Sentence]
type WordTally = [(String, Int)]

wordCountt :: Document -> WordTally
wordCountt [] = []
wordCountt [(x:xs), ys] = [(x, length (filter (x ==) (concat [(x:xs), ys])))] ++ wordCountt [xs, ys]```



```wordCountt [["a", "rose", "is", "a", "rose"],["but", "so", "is", "a", "rose"]]
[("a",3),("rose",3),("is",2),("a",2),("rose",2)*** Exception: CompLing.hs:(60,1)-(61,100): Non-exhaustive patterns in function wordCountt```
````

Comment: you can use `concat` to get rid of the list of list. But nevertheless, I think you make the problem more complicated by doing everything in a *single* function. Separate your concerns. Write helper functions that can for example merge two `WordTally`s. You might also want to take a look at `Map` which is a dictionary type.

Comment: Something else that is a problem here is the `[(x:xs), ys]` pattern. It means that you only match with lists of length *two*. So if the list contains one element, or three or more, it will raise an error. You should use the `(x:xs) : ys` pattern to match with non-empty lists.

Answer (score 3):

For making histograms, I always liked [`Map.fromListWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:fromListWith):

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import           Data.Map (Map)

histogram :: Ord a => [a] -> Map a Int
histogram xs = Map.fromListWith (+) (zip xs (repeat 1))
```

The way it works:

```
> zip (words "a rose is a rose") (repeat 1)
[("a",1),("rose",1),("is",1),("a",1),("rose",1)]

> Map.fromListWith (+) [("hello",1),("hello",1)]
fromList [("hello",2)]

> Map.fromListWith (+) [("a",1),("rose",1),("is",1),("a",1),("rose",1)]
fromList [("a",2),("is",1),("rose",2)]

> histogram (words "a rose is a rose")
fromList [("a",2),("is",1),("rose",2)]
```

So when the same word occurs in two (word, count) tuples, the counts get `+`'ed.

Comment: `zip xs (repeat)` is equivalent to `map (,1) xs` (with the `TupleSections` extension). Of course it will not matter (much) in terms of performance :)

Comment: Right. And `repeat 1` is equivalent to `[1,1..]`. I picked the one with less syntax. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you try to do *too* much in a single function. This means the function is harder to implement, debug, and perhaps most important, convincing yourself that it works.

We can split the function into two parts:

1. a function that adds a given element to a `WordTally`; and
2. a function that enumerates over all the words of the documents and keeps updating the `WordTally`.

The update function will look like:

```
addWord :: WordTally -> String -> WordTally
addWord = …
```

thus function thus takes a `WordTally` and a `String`. If the `String` ready is a "member" of the wordcount, then you increment the count, otherwise we add this with one. You can use explicit recursion for this.

Then the `wordCountt` is a fold-pattern on this. Indeed, we can make use of:

```
wordCountt :: Document -> WordTally
wordCountt d = foldl addWord [] (concat d)
```

or shorter:

```
wordCountt :: Document -> WordTally
wordCountt = foldl addWord [] . concat
```

We thus start with an empty list as `WordTally`, and each time add a element from the list of lists of a document and update the `WordTally` accordingly, until we reach the end of the words.

This will however not be very efficient, since updating the `WordTally` list, will take *O(n)* per word, and thus make this an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm. You can (later) look at [**`Map`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#t:Map) for example, which is a container that can insert/update in *O(log n)*.